# When I use php '->' in html doc it becomes a comment

Tags: php, html, wamp

I have this in my index.html file inside the body tag:

```
<?php 
require('db.php');
$a = new db();
$connection = $a->connect();
$name = $connection->getName($connection);
echo $name;
?>
```

But what chrome gets is:

```
<!--?php
require_once('dbconnect.php');
require('db.php');

$abc = new db();
$connection = $abc--->
connect();
$names = $connection-&gt;getNames($connection);
echo $names;

?>
```

I use chrome and wamp. Do you have any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: *"I have this int my index.html inside the body tag:"* - that's the problem; rename it to `index.php` unless you've instructed Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP.

Comment: I know php code should work in .html files, but try to change your index.html to index.php

Comment: The issue is with your fileName. Rename it to .php extension. Reason behind is that a normal html file wont be able to readh php tags.

Comment: @Andi PHP only works in HTML files if you've configured your Apache server to process the files as such...

Comment: `index.html`? Unless you told your webserver to run .html files through the php module, it's **NOT** going to get executed and the raw php code will be send to the browser, which will see your "invalid html" tags and do whatever it takes to fix them.

Comment: Or if you want/need the .html extension, configure Apache to have PHP process .html files too.

Comment: The fact that you came here to ask BEFORE trying to figure it out on your own (.html and not .php in filename) is what's actually shocking. I won't even downvote you, but you should quit doing anything related to computers with this level of laziness.

Comment: @War10ck good to know. Then I did this to my Server :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to rename your index.html file to index.php. 
If you haven't told your Apache server to treat .html files as .php files, your code just won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Any document with the .html extension will be default be read without the php/cgi compiler.  If you truly want to use PHP code in your pages you need to use the .php extension, or configure your Apache to open html pages with the php compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon how your server is configured, you might not be able to call PHP from HTML. To solve this, make one of the changes below to your .HTACCESS file either in the root folder or the folder where the html page is running:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

That directive will enable php in all html pages. If you just want to add it for one particular page, use this directive:

```
<Files index.html> 
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
</Files>
```

The above assumes that your page is named index.html, which is what your sample code indicates.